# Adjusting the physical dimensions of a Bitmap object

Tags: c#, bitmap, grasshopper

I have a script that returns a heatmap based on a `List` of Color objects (they're RGB values derived from a Gradient component in a graphical "coding" software called Grasshopper), which looks like this:

[image]

Below is an excerpt of my C# heatmap-drawing method that returns a `Bitmap`.

```
  private Bitmap DrawHeatmap(List<Color> colors, int U, int V){
    colorHeatmapArray = new Color[colors.Count()];

    for(int i = 0; i < colors.Count(); i++){
      colorHeatmapArray[i] = colors[i];
    }

    // Create heatmap image.
    Bitmap map = new Bitmap(U, V, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < colors.Count(); i++){
      Color color = colorHeatmapArray[i];
      map.SetPixel(x, y, color);
      y++;
      if (y >= map.Height){
        y = 0;
        x++;
      }
      if (x >= map.Width){
        break;
      }
    }
    return map;
  }
```

The method I used to save the image is like this:

```
  private void saveBMP(){
    _heatmap.Save(Path); // Path is just a string declared somewhere
  }
```

`_heatmap` is an instance variable, declared like this: `private Bitmap _heatmap;`, where I stored the `Bitmap` object, using the `DrawHeatmap()` method.

The way I displayed the image on the "canvas" of Grasshopper relies on some Grasshopper-specific method, specifically, this snippet

```
RectangleF rec = Component.Attributes.Bounds;
rec.X = rec.Right + 10;
rec.Height = Height;
rec.Width = Width;

canvas.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
canvas.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
canvas.Graphics.DrawImage(_heatmap, GH_Convert.ToRectangle(rec));
canvas.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
canvas.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Default;
canvas.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, GH_Convert.ToRectangle(rec));
```

However, when I save the `Bitmap` object, the result I get is a slightly taller version of what I have on the canvas, which looks like this:

[image]

Doesn't look very pretty does it?

My question is - on calling the `saveBMP()` method, is there a way to manipulate the `Bitmap` to adjust the dimensions so it looks remotely like what I have on the canvas?

Comment: I don't see an obvious way that the top image got mapped to the bottom one.  It looks similar, the top one also looks like it got painted by Edward Scissorhands.  Can't make fine wine out of sour grapes, "pretty" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Well, the `RectangleF` code snippet is what does the display of the heatmap onto the canvas. No dimensional changes are done to the `_heatmap` object. It never gets altered. My question is, is there a way to manipulate the dimensions of the `Bitmap` object on pressing `saveBMP()`? I'm not sure if I am wording it properly here..

Comment: No, that's not possible.  The size of the bitmap is fixed when you create the Bitmap object.  U and V in this code.  If you rescale an image to make it fit a bitmap then you're very interested in the InterpolationMode property.  NearestNeighbor is very fast, it is not very pretty.  You don't care about fast when you use SetPixel().

Comment: So you're saying `InterpolationMode` is what I should look into in order to change the dimensions?

Comment: No, set U and V to the required size OR save it as is, then create a new Graphics object and use DrawImage and a rectangle, but this will stretch the image and may cause distortion.

Comment: Dave how do you set the U and V to the required size? What method is it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the _heatmap is set from the output of the DrawHeatmap method, then its size should be being set at the point of initialisation in that method to U by V pixels. Once it's saved, verify from the saved file what the size of the output file (ie are it's dimensions as expected given the value of U and V that enter DrawHeatmap?

When you are drawing to the rectangle in the latter code section, are you using the same Height and Width values as earlier?

Comment: The `Height` and `Width` is set by this snippet `rec.Height = Height;
rec.Width = Width;`, with the assignment done by a slider as shown above in the screenshot. With that said, that `Height` and `Width` only changes the canvas drawing's height and width. The manipulation isn't done on the `_heatmap` object. Is there a way to manipulate the dimensions of the `Bitmap` object on pressing `saveBMP()`?

Comment: To my knowledge you don't set height and width when bitmaps are saved, those are fixed when creating the bitmap object. It seems like your code should generate the original HEatmap at U by V pixels, save it, then the second block is loading that saved bitmap onto another graphics object using DrawImage. That all sounds like it should work in essence. What are the values of U and V, what dimensions is the first saved image, what settings of Height and Width do you use, and what is the overall output?

Comment: I understand that, hence why the image looks elongated like that. Each pixel is occupying the same height and width, but there are more height pixels than there are width values. However, is there a way to change the dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

After some Googling it looks like I found a solution from this [link](http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp/applicationdesign/lesson10.htm)

Specifically:

[image]